# why clicking a hyperlink in excel will generate an HTTP request with MSIE 7.0 in User Agent?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, browser, user-agent

Our application would export an Excel containing hyperlink data. If clicking on the hyperlink, the browser will automatically lead to a specific page. I am using IE8 on Windows XP.

Now, I noticed below behaviors in Fiddler:

1. when clicking the hyperlink in Excel, the User Agent in HTTP request looks like below:

   *User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0;....*
2. above step actually opens the login page. If I enter user credential and login, then the User Agent would be like below:
   *User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0...*

My doubt is: why MSIE 7.0 is used in Step 1, while I was using IE8.0? (I didn't enable Compatibility view during the testing)

Comment: Sounds  like a compatibility mode issue. What kind of a link is this? Is it a local or LAN link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/03/10/more-ie8-extensibility-improvements.aspx) answers my doubt. After I added below, MSIE 8.0 was used in user agent (when clicking hyperlink from excel)

[(HKEY_CURRENT_USER or HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION] 
"excel.exe" = dword 8888

Comment: Correct. By default, non-IE applications default to CompatView by default. What version of Excel are you using? My guess is that you're using a version that still uses HLINK.DLL, which invokes URLMon in-process if IE is the default browser.

Comment: This happened on both excel 2007 and 2010. IE is not my default browser.